# Accessing data within MS Access database from visual studio C# Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, ms-access

I am currently having an issue with getting the data from my Access database and displaying it into my visual studio app.  The database and app is set up and linked correctly, I just need to know the code that allows you to search within the Access database (using a primary key) to receive the data in a different column and insert it into a string in the C# code.  For example:

I have a row with id = 3 within the Access database and need to access the data of a different column within that same row.  What I need to know is how to search for that id using C# code in the microsoft form and setting a string equal to that data in the database.

Comment: You might want to read up on ADO.NET. This is a pretty simple task using that technology.

Comment: For us to answer the question, we'll need to know *how* the database and app are connected.  What method are you using to read (and write) data from (and to) the database?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Windows 7, the Jet Engine does not work.